# Allow access to one AWS security group to another using terraform

Tags: terraform

I want to give an access to one security group to another but I am not able to get it work, can somebody point me, where I am doing wrong.

here is my module's **main.tf**:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "rds_sg" {
    name = "${var.name}-${var.environment}-rds"
    description = "Security Group ${var.name}-${var.environment}"
    vpc_id = "${var.vpc_id}"
    tags {
        Name = "${var.name}-${var.environment}-rds"
        environment =  "${var.environment}"
    }

    // allows traffic from the SG itself
    ingress {
        from_port = 0
        to_port = 0
        protocol = "-1"
        self = true
    }

    // allow traffic for TCP 3306
    ingress {
        from_port = 3306
        to_port = 3306
        protocol = "tcp"
        security_group_id = "${var.security_group_id}"
    }

    // outbound internet access
    egress {
        from_port = 0
        to_port = 0
        protocol = "-1"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
}

output "rds_sg_id" {
    value = "${aws_db_security_group.rds_sg.id}"
}
```

Module's **variables.tf**:

```
// Module specific variables
variable "name" {
    default = "test"
}

variable "environment" {
    default = "test"
}

variable "vpc_id" {
    description = "The VPC this security group will go in"
}

variable "security_group_id" {
    description = "Security Group id"
}
```

where the value of security_groups_id came to another module, so in my main file it is like this:

```
module "rds_sg" {
    source = "./modules/rds_sg"
    name = "tendo"
    environment = "dev"
    vpc_id = "${module.vpc_subnets.vpc_id}"
    security_group_id = "${module.web_sg.web_sg_id}"
}
```

but when I try to execute the "terraform", I am getting this error:

```
Errors:

  * 1 error(s) occurred:

* module root: module rds_sg: security_group_id is not a valid parameter
```

Comment: Looking at that error message I get the feeling that security_group_id doesn't exist inside the module. Can you show use the module code?

Comment: @LiamJones kindly review, I have update the question with all the necessary details. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I've found the issue; you're using the wrong argument for providing security groups in the module's main.tf. See the modified code below and the documentation [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/security_group.html).

```
// allow traffic for TCP 3306
ingress {
    from_port = 3306
    to_port = 3306
    protocol = "tcp"
    security_groups = ["${var.security_group_id}"]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Implementing the rule using `aws_security_group_rule` Terraform resource.

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "ingress" {
  type                     = "ingress"
  from_port                = 3306
  to_port                  = 3306
  protocol                 = "tcp"
  source_security_group_id = var.security_group_id
  security_group_id        = aws_security_group.rds_sg.id
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following worked for me, here i am allowing all port for one security group.

```
  ingress {
     from_port   = 0
     to_port     = 65535
     protocol    = "tcp"
     security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.OTHER_SECURITY_GROUP_NAME.id}"]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Output the ID of the security group as a variable.

```
output "rds_sg_id" {
  value = "${aws_security_group.rds_sg.id}"
}
```

When using the security group

```
// allow traffic for TCP 3306
    ingress {
        from_port = 3306
        to_port = 3306
        protocol = "tcp"
        security_group_id = "${var.rds_sg_id}"
    }
```

Comment: I did the same, but still getting an error, can you please review my updated question. Thanks